# How to use OUTPUT to capture new and old ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example let say I have,

```
    create table product
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      Name VARCHAR(10)
    )

    insert into product(Name) values('a')
    insert into product(Name) values('b')
    insert into product(Name) values('c')
    insert into product(Name) values('d')
    insert into product(Name) values('e')

    create table #tempproduct
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      Name VARCHAR(10)
    )

    declare @OutputAttributesValues table
    (
      [NewID] INT, 
      [OldID] INT
    )

    insert into #tempproduct(Name)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID],[ID] INTO @OutputAttributesValues
    select [Name] FROM product
```

See I need to get both Old and new ID from output. But this sql giving me error "Invalid column name 'ID'." http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a27b2/1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use traditional `INSERT` to output non-inserted fields.
Use merge instead (caveat: only works with database compatibility >= 100):

```
MERGE
  #tempproduct AS t
USING(
  SELECT
      Name
      , ID
  FROM
    product) AS s
ON (1=0)  
WHEN NOT MATCHED   
  THEN INSERT (Name) VALUES (Name)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, s.ID INTO @OutputAttributesValues;

SELECT * FROM @OutputAttributesValues
```

Comment: Jamie Thompson had an [excellent article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx) on this also. The only issue I've ever had with this method was when there is an INSTEAD OF trigger on the same table.

Comment: what is database compatibility >= 100

Comment: It's for SQL server 2008. I mention that despite you already tag 2008 - because some systems still set the database compatibility to something less than 100

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output both the `ID` from the `Products` table as well as the newly created `ID INT IDENTITY` from the temp table, then you need to extend that temp table to include the `Products.ID` column as well:

```
create table #tempproduct
(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   OldID INT,
   Name VARCHAR(10)
)

declare @OutputAttributesValues table
(
  [NewID] INT, 
  [OldID] INT
)

insert into #tempproduct(OldID, Name)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], Inserted.OldID INTO @OutputAttributesValues
  select ID, [Name] FROM product
```