# Using output to capture auto increment identity, plus past identity mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make exact copies of data in SQL, with new clientIDs, but keep the existing data in the old client as well. I will be inserting the data into a table with an auto incrementing integer primary key ID. I need to retain the ID's of the Old records and the new records together so I can continue using this mapping as I copy the different table data so I can maintain relationships.

At this point I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Driver]
OUTPUT inserted.ID
       inserted.Name
       inserted.ClientID
SELECT Name,
       1234 AS clientID
FROM dbo.Driver
```

I am wondering if there is a way to also select the old ID of the driver in the Output so I can then insert all of this into a holding table using the OUTPUT. So I need to end up with the following after I perform the insert into the dbo.Driver table so I can also insert these values into a temp table:

```
NewID
OldID
Name
ClientID
```

At this point I don't know of a way to pull the Original ID from the original record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MERGE INTO to keep track of the old ID as per the following SO post:
[How to use OUTPUT to capture new and old ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620044/how-to-use-output-to-capture-new-and-old-id)

Answer (score 0):

you can try...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Driver (oldID, Name, clientID)
SELECT
   B.ID,
   A.Name,
   1234 AS clientID
FROM dbo.Driver A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Driver B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.clientID = b.clientID
```

or maybe just

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Driver (oldID, Name, clientID)
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    1234 AS clientID
FROM dbo.Drive
```